# Maven fails to download CoreNLP models

Tags: maven, stanford-nlp

When building the sample application from the Stanford CoreNLP website, I ran into a curious exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:493)
…
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as either class path, filename or URL
…
```

This only happened when the property `pos` and the ones after it were included in the properties.

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

Here is the dependency from my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I actually found the answer to that in the problem description of another question on Stackoverflow.

[Quoting W.P. McNeill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250476/maven-dependencyget-does-not-download-stanford-nlp-model-files):

> Maven does not download the model files automatically, but only if you
>   add models line to the .pom. Here is a .pom
>   snippet that fetches both the code and the models.

Here's what my dependencies look like now:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The important part to note is the entry `<classifier>models</classifier>` at the bottom. In order for Eclipse to maintain both references, you'll need to configure a dependency for each `stanford-corenlp-3.2.0` and `stanford-corenlp-3.2.0-models`.

Comment: In case you are using SBT, you can add the following lines to the library dependencies sequence :  "edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.2.0", "edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.2.0" classifier "models"

Comment: @eliasah: I am doing the same thing as you have stated in your comment , but its not downloading the models ! Its been 2 hrs and still it has not downloaded anything related to models !

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to use the models for other languages (like Chinese, Spanish, or Arabic) you can add the following piece to your `pom.xml` file (replace `models-chinese` with `models-spanish` or `models-arabic` for these two languages, respectively):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <classifier>models-chinese</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

With Gradle apparently you can use:

```
implementation 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.9.2'
implementation 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.9.2:models'
```

or if you use compile (depricated):

```
compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.9.2'
compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.9.2' classifier: 'models'
```