# Getting Stanford Core NLP through Maven

Tags: java, maven, stanford-nlp

I am doing a project on text categorization using Stanford NLP in Java. To get the API, I added the dependencies in my POM file.

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
       <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
       <version>3.5.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
       <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
       <version>3.5.0</version>
       <classifier>models</classifier>
   </dependency>
```

When I do maven update/install I am getting the below error message :

```
 Failure to transfer edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:jar:models:3.5.0 from    http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:jar:models:3.5.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000.
```

I found  a similar question here - [Maven dependency:get does not download Stanford NLP model files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14250476/1930402) . But, I am unable to find a solution anywhere. Any help please?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps Maven is in an inconsistent state? Have you tried something like:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

The dependencies I use -- which look identical to yours above -- are:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.0</version>
  <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
```